# GLUT keyboard and mouse func just won't get called

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, listeners

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, const_cast<char**>(argv));
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("Sample Window");
    glutDisplayFunc(render);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void keyboard(unsigned char c, int x, int y){
     std::cout << "Called Keyboard";
    if(c == 'a'){
        exit(0);
    }
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){
    std::cout << "Called Mouse";
    if(button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON){
        exit(0);
    }
}

void render(){
}
```

So, I have a problem with the above code. The keyboard and mouse function just won't get called.

I hope you can manage to reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple, you forgot to register them using `glutKeyboardFunc` and `glutMouseFunc`:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, const_cast<char**>(argv));
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("Sample Window");
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutDisplayFunc(render);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's what school does to you... Thanks @Thomas. Worked perfectly.